# How to get current animateFloatAsState value when target value changed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I'm trying to do some animation with JetPack Compose animation. And I need some help for my example.

```
@Composable
fun RotateTest(
    inputRotation:Int, 
){

    val rotationAnim by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = inputRotation.toFloat(),
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 5000
            )
        )
     
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).graphicsLayer {
        rotationZ = rotationAnim
    }, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center){
        Text(text = "rotating text")
    }
    
}
```

It's works fine, stops and restarted when new  input arrives. But i see a problem with a static duration time. 5 sec is fine for 0 to 180 degree rotation but very long for 0 to 10. So I decided to change the static time value to a value based on the current and target rotation, something like:

```
...
animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 
<current rotation - target rotation * speed modifier>
            )
        )
...
```

But I don't understand how to get the current rotation value of the animator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
val rotationAnim = remember { Animatable(inputRotation.toFloat()) }

LaunchedEffect(inputRotation) {
    val current = rotationAnim.value
    if (inputRotation.toFloat() != current) {
        rotationAnim.animateTo(
            inputRotation.toFloat(),
            tween(/* your calculation */),
        )
    }
}
```